# Using Travis CI with Swift 3.0 & CocoaPods

Tags: ios, github, swift3, cocoapods, travis-ci

I am trying out TravisCI since I got it in my GitHub Education Pack.

I am doing TDD on iOS 10.1.

I could not yet figure out how to configure TravisCI for Swift 3.0, iOS 10.1 and using CocoaPods.

I managed to link TravisCI with my Repository. But other than that, I always get a "Build Failed" message.

Not sure if important, but I did not have the Pod folder in my Repo.

I saw a tutorial for TravisCI & Swift and recreated the travis.yml from there which looks like that:

```
language: objective-c

branches:
 only:
 - master
 - Development

xcode_project: Friendschallenge.xcodeproj
xcode_scheme: FriendschallengeTests
osx_image: xcode8.1
xcode_sdk: iphonesimulator10.1

script:
- xcodebuild clean build test -project Friendschallenge.xcodeproj -scheme FriendschallengeTests
```

I hope you can help me.

Edit 1:

Here is the log of the latest commit:

[TravisCI Log](http://www.mediafire.com/file/uywj8dw978qz3xu/travis-log)

Comment: Please include the logs in the question.

Comment: I think you are missing the configuration try locally this command before testing on Travic again to avoid waisting the time waiting for Travis: xcodebuild clean build test -project Friendschallenge.xcodeproj -scheme FriendschallengeTests  -configuration Debug. if not to set xcode provisionning to Automatic. the error is coming from your commited project mentionning you local machine PF and Cetificate.

Comment: Running this gives me an error: "A build only device cannot be used to run this target"

How may I select the target?

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen this error?

`No profiles for 'com.simnik.Friendschallenge' were found:  Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching 'com.simnik.Friendschallenge'.
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.1'
** BUILD FAILED **`

According to it - you need to use proper provisioning profile.

More info on it you may find [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppStoreDistributionTutorial/CreatingYourTeamProvisioningProfile/CreatingYourTeamProvisioningProfile.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check your provisioning profile with associated certificates. Here check link about Apple Troubleshooting [Apple Troubleshooting](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Troubleshooting/Troubleshooting.html).About Signing Identities and Certificates[Code signing](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html).Here link for making signing certificate and provisioning profile[Tutorial](http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/cordova/code-signing-your-app/configuring-code-signing-for-ios-apps/create-development-certificate)